# Find documents in MongoDB using result of another query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, robo3t

I'm new to MongoDB and I'm trying to find documents in collection `A`, where field `_id` is equal to field `excel_template` from collection `B`.

```
var r = db.B.find({"name":/.*aco.*/}, {excel_template:1, _id:0}).excel_template;
db.A.find({"_id":{$eq: "${r}" }})
```

but I have hard time doing it. It gives me no results while it should give me one result. Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: `db.A.find({"_id":{$in: r}})` ?..

Comment: `Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $in needs an array`

Comment: and if you `var r = db.B.find({"name":/.*aco.*/}, {excel_template:1, _id:0});
db.A.find({"_id":{$in: r.excel_template}})` ?..

Comment: `error: {
 "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $in needs an array",
 "code" : 17287
}`

Comment: what mongo version you run?

Comment: version 3.0.12.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**[`find`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** returns a [`cursor`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-cursor) to the matching documents. So the query

```
db.B.find({ "name": /.*aco.*/ }, { "excel_template": 1, "_id": 0 })
```

will not return a single document but a [`cursor`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-cursor) to the documents that match the query criteria above.

You can either use the **[`distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)** method to return an array of `excel_template` values from documents that match the query above and use that in the other query as in:

```
var r = db.B.distinct("excel_template", { "name": /.*aco.*/ });
db.A.find({ "_id": { "$in": r } });
```

OR

---

**MongoDB 3.2 and newer:**

You can also use the aggregation framework where the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** pipeline will provide a functionality to join the two collections and run the query in a single operation

```
db.B.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "name": /.*aco.*/ } },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "A",
            "localField": "excel_template",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "bList"
        }
    }
])
```